# Power Query multiply column using variable column name from excel range

Tags: powerquery

I'm having problems with a code line in Power Query : I want to add a new column multiplying by 2 one existing column of my table.
The difficulty for me here is that the column that I will multiply by 2 will be defined by a cell value contained in the same Excel worksheet.

My question is : how can I add a new column knowing that the reference of the existing column is given by a cell value?

I'm trying something like this, but not working :

```
#"Add FAT" = Table.AddColumn(#"Add YEAR", "FAT (g/100 g)", each Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Fat_variable"]}[Content][Colonne1]{0}*2)
```

Thank you all !!

Comment: Where exactly is your problem? What does `not working` mean? Error message? Crashes? If an error message what is it? Break your statement into separate steps. Are you returning the desired column name? Or is the problem further down the line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
#"Add FAT" = Table.AddColumn(#"Add YEAR", "FAT (g/100 g)", each Record.Field(_,Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Fat_variable"]}[Content]{0}[Column1])*2)
```

where Fat_variable is a defined single cell range that contains a Column name

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I needed and what made me crazy the whole morning. Thank you @horseyride

Comment: All right, Done !